# How to retrieve http 302 response in angular

Tags: internet-explorer, angular5

I am making one api call whose response is http 302, which in turn is making another api call. The second call is done by browser on which we have no control. I get the response of second call in first call success on chrome and firefox but in IE I am not getting the response of second in first call success. How can I get the second call response in IE. I have tried to extract response in interceptor as well but second redirection call is not passed through interceptor as well. I mean angular doesn't seem to have control on redirection call. Can anybody help here?

Thanks

Comment: have you ever tried to set break point in the first call success function, to check if there is any error in IE browser, try to use F12 developer tools to debug it.

Comment: Yes, that was the first task which I did. There's no error as both the calls are getting success.